# Display last two rows from MySQL database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display only the columns timein and timeout from the last two rows of my table StudentInfo.
Heres the code:

```
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT timein, timeout 
    FROM studentInfo
    WHERE name = 'Student' 
    ORDER BY time DESC
    LIMIT 2
    ")
    or die("Error querying database ".mysql_error());
while($minutes = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo "timein: ".$minutes['timein']."<br />";
  echo "timeout: ".$minutes['timeout']."<br />";
```

Comment: Use `print_r($minutes);` instead.

Comment: Other than the usage of the deprecated and vulnerable `mysql_` library, I don't see what the problem is? you're getting all your rows, then you're ordering them from last to first, and then you're grabbing  the top 2 rows from that resultset.

Comment: Do you appreciate the differenec between a table and a database?

Comment: Get rid of the parenthesis around `name = 'Student'`.

Comment: So, what is the problem actually? try `dd($minutes);` to catch the data.

Comment: @majimboo `dd()` is not a standard php function. It looks to be a Laravel helper function - http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#miscellaneous

Comment: So why don't you tell us that error?!

Comment: Error querying database

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is?

Comment: @Sean oh yeah I missed that.

Comment: the error is: Error querying database. The problem is in the query.

Comment: Is the exact error message?

Comment: Error querying database

Comment: `echo mysql_error();` instead of the `die`.

Comment: change your `or die("Error querying database");` to `or die("Error querying database ".mysql_error());` so you know what the mysql error is.

Comment: @Sean Changed it. New error: Error querying database Unknown column 'id' in 'order clause'

Comment: Query is fine. there is no problem in the query. Do you really have `id` column in your studentinfo table. What's the structure of your StudentInfo table?

Comment: Is there a column named `id` in your `studentInfo` table?

Comment: @user3357123, that means there is no column called 'id' in your table...

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT timein, timeout  FROM studentInfo WHERE name = 'Student'  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2") or die(mysql_error());

while($minutes = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
  echo "timein: ".$minutes['timein']."<br />";
  echo "timeout: ".$minutes['timeout']."<br />";
}
```

--

try to use mysql mysqli since this deprecated